# Converting sync to async code got unhandled System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, task

I'm trying to convert my sync functions to async. In all my sync functions I have a cancellation token which is used on function, task and parallel blocks. I have a try/catch block before calling the async function, but I'm getting an unhandled exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in
> System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll An exception of type
> 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in
> System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll but was not handled in user code
> The operation was canceled.

My async function:

```
public async Task DecodeAsync(string? fileFullPath, FileDecodeType fileDecodeType, OperationProgress? progress = null) =>
            await Task.Run(() => Decode(fileFullPath, fileDecodeType, progress), progress?.Token ?? default);
```

How I call it:

```
try
        {
            await SlicerFile.DecodeAsync(fileName, fileDecodeType, Progress);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Do not work!
        catch (Exception exception) // Works for other exceptions
        {
            await this.MessageBoxError(exception.ToString(), "Error opening the file");
        }
```

`catch (OperationCanceledException)` is never reached nor `catch (Exception exception)` in a cancel event. As my try is at top most, why doesn't it catch the exception?

But if I do:

```
public async Task DecodeAsync(string? fileFullPath, FileDecodeType fileDecodeType, OperationProgress? progress = null) =>
            await Task.Run(() => throw new Exception("Test"));
```

I get the exception catch on the generic Exception (it's handled)

In other hand with old code it's working and handling the `OperationCanceledException`:

```
var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {
            try
            {
                SlicerFile.Decode(fileName, fileDecodeType, Progress);
                return true;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) {} // Works!
            catch (Exception exception) 
            {
                Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                    await this.MessageBoxError(exception.ToString(), "Error opening the file"));
            }

            return false;
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what does the stack trace of that cancellation exception look like? where was it actually thrown? That's probably more important than the other code you have included in your question.

Comment: it come from a parallel cancelation: https://github.com/sn4k3/UVtools/blob/19a0ff5496b0cdac950468451a559103bb41905f/UVtools.Core/FileFormats/CXDLPFile.cs#L928

Comment: You're passing the same cancellation token to `Task.Run`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action-system-threading-cancellationtoken) "A cancellation token allows the work to be cancelled if it has not yet started." seems ... odd.

Comment: Yes, both Task.Run and Parallel are sharing the same token. If i place a try/catch inside the Task.Run it works

Comment: Do you observe this behavior only when you are running your app from the Visual Studio with the debugger attached, or the same thing happens also if you run it without the debugger? (with Ctrl+F5)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias without the debugger the app just crash and exit. If i put a try/catch inside the Task.Run the debugger shows the exception first but is able to continue happily due it's handled

Comment: I wouldn't expect this code to crash, without the debugger. Could you edit the question and include a minimal compilable and runnable example that reproduces the crash?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i was able to fix the major problem, following Jonh V suggestion to not await Task.Run on my Async method and unmark it as async, so i end with:  

 `public Task DecodeAsync(string? fileFullPath, FileDecodeType fileDecodeType, OperationProgress? progress = null) => Task.Run(() => Decode(fileFullPath, fileDecodeType, progress), progress?.Token ?? default);`

Now it handle the OperationCanceledException on root try/catch but VS debugger still kicks in and pause executation to show the exception on the Parallel which is annoying in a development environment...

Comment: One way to prevent debugger to kick in is to use try/catch inside the Task.Run to handle the OperationCanceledException but that also prevent codders from catch this event and do something regard a cancellation if they wish to. Is there anyway to prevent debugger to show in this "fake" unhandled exception?

Comment: Main question was infact due the unhandled exception and program crash. I'm accepting Jonh V as awnser as it solved the main problem. The debugger question is secondary and come in after the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of Task.Run don't need to be awaited right there necessarily. You can just return the running Task and then the method doesn't need to be awaited or be async any longer.

```
    Task DecodeAsync(string? fileFullPath, FileDecodeType fileDecodeType, OperationProgress? progress = null) => Task.Run(() => 
Decode(fileFullPath, fileDecodeType, progress), progress?.Token ?? default);
```

And since you're passing in progress with a token, you can monitor that to exit the decode method cleanly instead of trying to catch and ignore the operation cancelled exception.

You'll have better luck if you make the decode method itself asynchronous if you can. It already returns a Task, so it could return a Task (or whatever). Your old code is also asynchronous in the same way, so there's no advantage to your new code that I can see.

Comment: Removing await did not solve the problem but also adds warnings: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS4014 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

"exit the decode method cleanly" -- You mean check for cancellation and return null ?

Comment: I mean to do whatever makes sense for this function. Wrapping synch methods in Task.Run(() => ) to make them async is not the ideal scenario. Just make Decode Async and have it return the decoded information.